# Column selection to lastrow then resize

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that finds the last row of data in column E and selects the column to that last row. I want to be able to select associated data in columns B through D that goes with column E and then sort based on column B. So I thought I would just find the last row in column E then resize by 3 columns and sort from that selection but I keep getting a run-time error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error. I have provided the code I'm using below. Columns B through D contain data past the end of column E. Thanks!

```
ws.Range("E1:E" & finalrow).Resize(0, 3).Select
```

Comment: try this: `ws.Range("E1:E" & finalrow).Resize(finalrow, -4).Select`. You need to tell the Resize function how many rows as well. It's not like the `Offset` method.

Comment: You rock! I knew I was doing something stupid. Thanks so much :)

Comment: sorry, I just tested the `-` in the Resize and it failed. You may need to do this: `ws.Range("B1:B" & finalrow).Resize(finalrow, 4).Select`

Comment: Yeah I dont think it will let you go negative for some reason

Comment: offset does, so I was thinking it would follow suit, but nope :(

Comment: darn oh well lol thanks anyways

Comment: this code: `ws.Range("E1:E" & finalrow).Offset(, -3).Resize(finalrow, 3).Select` will select cells from `B1` to `D & finalrow` if this is correct result you can use this line: `Range("B1:D" & finalrow).Select` to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You may not always be starting in the first row (e.g. `E1`) so *lastRow* may not be applicable without some maths. In that case, use [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)s to shorten the code while explicitly referencing the correct cell and cell ranges.

```
dim lastRow as long
with ws
    lastRow = .cells(.rows.count, "E").end(xlup).row
    'option 1
    .range("B5:D" & lastRow).select

    'option 2
    with .range("E5:E" & lastRow)
        .offset(0, -3).resize(.rows.count, 3).select
    end with

    'option 3
    .range("E5", .cells(lastRow, "G")).offset(0, -3).select
end with
```

---

<sub>See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on [Range.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197597.aspx) and [Range.Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221681.aspx) to accomplish your goals.</sub>

Comment: I tried all 3 of these and I keep getting the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Sub SelectLast3Cols()

Dim ws As Worksheet, lrow As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet3")
lrow = ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ws.Range("B1", ws.Range("D" & lrow)).Select

End Sub
```